# Can we link to OpenSTV in the Ubuntu repos on the election page?

Tags: feature-request, election

The [election results](https://askubuntu.com/election/2) tell you that you can use OpenSTV to audit the results and provide links to windows and mac installers. This is Ask Ubuntu. We don't need to download random installers from the web. [OpenSTV](http://packages.ubuntu.com/openstv) [Install openstv http://hostmar.co/software-small](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/openstv) is available in the Ubuntu archives.

[image: OpenSTV on Ubuntu]

I know that this isn't going to come up for another year, but it would be nice to have an Ubuntu install link included:

[Install via the software center http://hostmar.co/software-banner](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/openstv)

Comment: +1, we discussed this in chat before the election but we figured it was too late to bring it up then.

Comment: A year goes by and another election is over, still not implemented...

Answer (score 8):

## Yes.

We support and answer almost everything Ubuntu, let's change the link for this election, while there is still time to at least get a fix in after-the-fact.

Answer (score 6):

I hate to bump this up, but I just visited the [2014 Moderator Election](https://askubuntu.com/election/4) page, and I was surprised to see that it only links downloads of OpenSTV for Windows and Mac:

[image]

And I thought, come *on*... this is Ask Ubuntu. It seems reasonable to assume most users here interested in downloading the election data are using Ubuntu rather than Windows or Mac. It's just a matter of `sudo apt-get install openstv`. It would be nice if the election page mentioned that.

So I went on ahead to point this out on Meta, but instead I found this question back from the 2012 elections... so I just wanted to bring it up again. It seems this still hasn't been done. Also, apologies if posting an answer to such an old question doesn't comply with the AskUbuntu-Netiquette, but I thought posting an exact duplicate question would be redundant also. :)